# Restrict SSH CA certificates to specific users/groups

Tags: ssh, openssh, certificates

Is it possible to restrict the use of CA certificates to specific users/principals/groups?

The use case is that I'd like to have 2 CA certificates. One would be used as part of an automated system to sign user keys. If this certificate were to be compromised, I want to be sure that it couldn't be used to allow someone to log into an admin account.

The other CA certificate would obviously be more securely stored (airgapped etc.) and used for admin accounts.

Comment: Just so I understand: you want to make sure that if CA1 erroneously certifies a public key for user `root`, it still would not work?

Comment: According to sshd docs, `TrustedUserCAKeys` is valid in `Match` sections, so I think that `Match User root` should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Ulrich Schwarz's comment:

If I add normal users to an `endusers` group, then I can set the sshd_config like this:

```
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/admin_ca.pub
Match Group endusers
    TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/user_ca.pub
```

This results in the user_ca only being accepted for users in the `endusers` group, while the admin_ca can be used for any user.

Comment: But you do not have to match the normal users for the protection you asked for but the admin accounts.

Comment: Both works. But, I'd rather restrict the less secure CA to a specific group of restricted users. That way I can be certain that this CA will never be used to log into any other account that may have less restrictions (admin or otherwise).